# How to use jQuery Ajax to get form data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

Experts,

In a MVC project we have a form which opens up with Jquery Windows.open() like this -

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=700,height=700,left=' + left + ',top=' + top);
```

The url is defined as -

```
var url = configMap.sitePath + 'supply-chain-pressure/EmailRequest';                                                    // localhost/controller/method

url += '?id=' + escape(params.id) + '&weakness=' + escape(params.weakness) + '&&percent=' + escape(params.percent);
```

The form starts like -

```
<form name="emailrequest" id="emailrequest" method="get">
.. diffrent elements
</form>
```

The above form has a diffrent text boxes and on the click of submitt button we want to get the val of all

the text boxes and the above mentioned url . I am using Jquery ajex Get() (with in the click of submit button) but all I get is mark up and HTML -

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: sitePath + 'supply-chain-pressure/EmailRequest',
data: $('#emailrequest').value,
success: function(data) {
alert(data);
}

});//End Ajax
```

the overall ask is to send the data to another controller methoda but before that I need the above data.Please help as to how can I get the data ?

Comment: var data = $( 'form' ).serialize();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the window save the reference to a variable, making sure the variable is in scope of your `$.ajax()` function:

```
var childWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'width=700,height=700,left=' + left + ',top=' + top);
```

Then you can use this reference in the jQuery selector:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: sitePath + 'supply-chain-pressure/EmailRequest',
    data: $('#emailrequest', childWindow.document).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi , Wont the url will be overidden with the url in ajax? or I should ask that how is that url , in child window diffrent from url in ajax

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin. It will help you to post the form like you are trying to do (with a reference just to the form and not for each input).

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 0):

Use serialize() if you want to get all data from your form

```
data: $('#emailrequest').serialize(),
```